# Android Photo Take and Send Server

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to take a photo and upload it to the server, but I'm outputting a thumbnail photo. How can I get it in Full-Size?

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Set");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Userınfo",0);
    email = sharedPreferences.getString("deneme",email);
    setContentView(R.layout.tamir_islem);
    qrcode=findViewById(R.id.qrcode);
    arizaPhoto = findViewById(R.id.arizafoto);
    imageShow = findViewById(R.id.arizafotoshow);

    arizaPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if(intent1.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivityForResult(intent1,CAMERA_ACTION_CODE);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(tester.this,"There is no app that support this action",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

I use this code for taking pictures and string operations.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_ACTION_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        finalPhoto = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
        System.out.println(bundle);
        System.out.println(finalPhoto);
        imageShow.setImageBitmap(finalPhoto);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        finalPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(byteArray));
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

I use this to send..

```
    @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("encoded",encoded);
            return param;
        }
```

Thank you for your attention. :)